# django include template with cycled variable

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a list of tasks with headers for task type groups.  I'm trying to move the task row (last `<tr>`) into its own template:

```
{% for task in tasks %}

{% ifchanged task.task_type %}
<tr>
    <td colspan="5"><br><h3>{{ task.task_type }}</h3></td>
</tr>
{% endifchanged %}
<tr class="{% cycle 'active' '' as rowcolor %}">
    ...
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

I know it's easy to make alternating row colors with CSS, but that might make some group header rows gray followed by a white row; I want all group header rows to be white and the subsequent rows for that group to start with a gray row.

What I'm trying to do is replace the last `<tr>` with

```
{% include '_row.html' with rowcolor="{% cycle 'active' '' %}" %}
```

But it appears that `{% %}` can't be nested.  Using `{{ }}` in the `rowcolor` value didn't work either.  Is there some way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
{% cycle 'active' '' as active_or_not silent %}
{% include '_row.html' with rowcolor=active_or_not %}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Ah, didn't know about the `silent` flag.  Thanks!

Comment: In Django 1.9 (only version I've tested) this does not allow the nested template to advance the cycle, only access the current value.